# why unordered associative containers do not use allocator_traits<T> in C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

Why don't C++0x unordered associative containers use allocator_traits to define their member types pointer and const_pointer?

For example, sequential and ordered associative containers use the following definition:

```
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer pointer;
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer const_pointer;
```

Whereas unordered associative containers use this:

```
typedef typename Allocator::pointer pointer;
typedef typename Allocator::const_pointer const_pointer;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything.  Here's your chance to participate in the standards process.  Please submit an issue.  The directions on how to do so are here:

http://lwg.github.com/issues/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

I scanned, but did not find an existing issue on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

This is now corrected in the current latest draft. For example page 788:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf

```
class unordered_set
{
public:
// types
.... .... .... 
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer pointer;
typedef typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer const_pointer;
.... .... ....
}
```

Interestingly, en.cppreference.com (incorrectly you could argue) agrees: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map